# How to stylize option element inside Select control css, jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Does someone know how to stylize option element inside Select control I tried with css like `select option{}` or i tried to put id, class and even I tried to put select into  but that doesn't work I want to change width, height, padding

Comment: The CSS you can place on `option` elements is very restricted. If you want to style them you would be best to use a third party library, such as Select2 or Chosen

Comment: But I don't use that library must be a way

Comment: No I'm afraid not.

Comment: It must be done with Jquery I tried one solution here but It doesn't work for me ?

Comment: It is a possible duplicate of this thread, you might find a solution here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: you will need JS to have the most consistent result ... hide the select and recreate that with another html elements.

Comment: thx @achref I tried this but id doesn't work for me

Comment: Yep which is what the libraries I mentioned in my first comment do. You can of course roll your own versions, but why re-invent the wheel for very little gain

Comment: That is exactly what they explained @jhony3 , select element is OS dependent so you probably need to find a workaround

Comment: That is the easy way It must be done with js